# Using conditional formatting to highlight cells that exceed the criteria below

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, conditional-statements

I'm working on a spreadsheet that lists width of a product in cell A, and height of a product in cell B. I'm trying to apply conditional formatting to highlight these cells if they surpass the limits set by the manufacturer's raw material size.

The raw material size is 120cm x 240cm. So essentially, if the width goes above 120cm, the height cannot exceed 120cm. Similarly, if the height exceeds 120cm, the width cannot exceed 120cm. And regardless, neither side can exceed 240cm.

I haven't been able to figure out how to translate this logic into a formula that conditional formatting can use to highlight these cells if they violate these limits.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try in a third column : `=IF(A1>120;AND(A1<240;B1<120);B1<240)` where A1 and B1 are your dimensions. This would give you TRUE if the dimensions are Ok, FALSE if not. Then you can apply a conditional formatting on this value.

If you don’t want to add a column, you can also « add a new rules », « use a formula … », type this formulae, and it will change the display when the condition is true…. On the first column. Replace A1 and B1 by $A1 and $B2 in this formulae to be adequate on the second column.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!